# Can't install extensions on CiviCRM 4.6.36 with Drupal 7.59

Tags: drupal, extension, installation

So I successfully installed CiviCRM and most things are running well but I can't install extensions.

From Gui
I get to the "Download and Install button and the installation fails with:

**WARNING: The downloader may be unable to download files which require HTTP redirection. This may be a configuration issue with PHP's open_basedir or safe_mode.
Unable to extract the extension.
Extension Upgrade Failed
Download failed - ZIP file is unavailable or malformed**

Manual
I download and expand the zip file in the extensions directory
It shows up as a local install
When I click the "Install" button:

**the browser shows an address of *(myserver)/drupal/index.php?q=civicrm/admin/extensions
And the message is:
This page isn’t working
(myserver) is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500***

I suspect some sort of PHP error but I don't know what the solution is.

Comment: So I've found part of the problem which deals with the manual install. It turns out the error was with one specific extension, the Mailchimp extension. In my server logs i found: "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/e-smith/files/ibays/drupal/html/sites/default/files/civicrm/custom_ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp-2.0.1/mailchimp.php on line 318"

Comment: Line 318 reads: " $js_safe_object = [ ];"  Other extensions install OK using the manual method.

Comment: Per answer below - even though 4.6 still supports php 5.4 there is no expectation that extensions will run on 5.4

Comment: Yes, PHP 5.6 solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax looks fine for me. You will need to check php version you are using. It should be 5.5 or more i believe.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, after updating to PHP 5.6 all is well.

Comment: Wow... Cheers (y)

Comment: Stephen - great that Pradeep helped you. Etiquette would be for you to 'accept' his answer as that helps guide others reading this

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is already answered here, but check your php version and configuration against the requirements here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#php

(Also, you might also want to check out 'clean-urls' in Drupal - https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/configuring-clean-urls/enable-clean-urls  That's not related to the cause of the problem but makes the URL's in your error message nicer)